# How to record video without taking up the whole screen

Tags: iphone, ios, video

I'm trying to implement a video recorder view controller that will be embedded inside of another view controller.

I implemented a MPMoviePlayedViewController, but that takes up the whole screen and is not what I want. I followed this tutorial, but did not get the results I was looking for - http://www.appcoda.com/video-recording-playback-ios-programming/

tl;dr - Is it possible to record a video without taking up the whole screen? How would one go about implementing that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `UIContainerView`.  It allows one `UIViewController` and its views to be displayed in a container of your desired size.  Similar to a `UITabBarController`, which displays its child view controllers in a specified part of the screen, not the whole screen.

For examples and documentation, check out Apple's (hopefully secure) Developer site.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The recorder is actually in a container view, but because (I think anyway) apple's recorder can only be fullscreen, it doesn't work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVFoundation to if you need more control see this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) to the apple documentation.

First setup your AVCaptureSession with an AVCaptureDevice, AVCaptureInput, and an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.
Second create the view you want to display the output in and add it to your view controller

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput= [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:nil];
[session addInput:videoInput];

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
UIView *videoDisplay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
previewLayer.frame = videoDisplay.bounds;
[videoDisplay.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
[session startRunning];
```